Quantstats utils.make_index() TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
While trying to use Quantstats utils.make_index() I am getting a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str' message. This is my code that caused the error:
import quantstats as qs
qs.extend_pandas()

IAC = {"SPY": 1.3, "AGG": -.3}

portfolio = qs.utils.make_index(IAC)

I even tested with other ticker combinations and directly entering the ticker and weights in make_index and the error repeats in the same way. I also tested in previous versions and the error repeats again. Does anyone know if there is an error in the package or is it my code?
The Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\whohe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\quantstat_portfolio.py", line 31, in <module>
    portfolio = qs.utils.make_index(IAC,rebalance='1M',period='max',returns=None,match_dates=False)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\whohe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\quantstats\utils.py", line 400, in make_index
    return index[index.index <= last_day].sum(axis=1)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\whohe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 11670, in sum
    result = super().sum(axis, skipna, numeric_only, min_count, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\whohe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 12506, in sum
    return self._min_count_stat_function(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\whohe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 12489, in _min_count_stat_function
    return self._reduce(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\whohe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 11562, in _reduce
    res = df._mgr.reduce(blk_func)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\whohe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1500, in reduce
    nbs = blk.reduce(func)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\whohe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 404, in reduce
    result = func(self.values)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\whohe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 11481, in blk_func
    return op(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\whohe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 85, in _f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\whohe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 404, in new_func
    result = func(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, mask=mask, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\whohe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 477, in newfunc
    return func(values, axis=axis, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\whohe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 646, in nansum
    the_sum = values.sum(axis, dtype=dtype_sum)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\whohe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 49, in _sum
    return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'


Please post the full error traceback message.

Traceback added

The error message has portfolio = qs.utils.make_index(IAC,rebalance='1M',period='max',returns=None,match_dates=False) which does not match the posted code.  It's very hard to help when you do not share the real code.
